# Undefined variable pylint error for SConstruct file

Tags: python, scons, pylint

When I open the SConstruct file from my project, the pylint reports error:

```
"Undefined variable 'Environment'
```

on code:

```
env = Environment()
```

What import should be added to make sure pylint can find definition of `Environment`?

Comment: Likely you should have ```Environment()``` and not ```Environment ()```. That said not sure that Pylint can currently be simply configured to not flag this as an error.  So you'll have to just ignore SCons API call warnings from pylint.

Comment: @bdbaddog That extra space is a typo in my post, not in my code.

Comment: try `from SCons.Script import Environment`